# Wordpress: Change message given when deleting post from custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type, notice

So I have a custom post type called members. linked with advanced custom fields.
I've made it so if I delete a member from the custom post type it doesn't move to the trash and permanently deletes it. but I still get this message:

[image]

---

I'm trying to change this message.

the line I'm trying to override inside `/wp-admin/edit.php` is:

```
'trashed'   => _n( '%s post moved to the Trash.', '%s posts moved to the Trash.', $bulk_counts['trashed'] ),
```

the code I've tried inside `functions.php` to change it is as follows:

```
add_filter( 'post_trashed_messages', function( $messages )
{
    $messages['post'][2] = 'Succesfully deleted';
    return $messages;
} );
```

I've it's not possible to change it. 
is it then possible to maybe remove the notice entirely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so how I got it to work is like this:

```
add_filter( 'bulk_post_updated_messages', function ( $bulk_messages, $bulk_counts ) {
    $bulk_messages['post']['trashed'] = _n( '%s post successfully deleted.', '%s posts successfully deleted.', $bulk_counts['trashed'] );
    return $bulk_messages;
}, 10, 2 );
```